# Update existing row in database in forms - Django

Tags: python, django

I have an existing entry in the database, and i want to check in my    views.py if the entry already exists in the DB, if it does then the    new values will replace the old data in that row, otherwise create a    new row for that user. How can i do that?

```
#models.py
class Member(models.Model):
username = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True)
password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, null=True)
following = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=True)

class Message(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='%(class)s_user')
recip = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='%(class)s_recip')
pm = models.BooleanField(default=True)
time = models.DateTimeField()
text = models.CharField(max_length=4096)


def __str__(self):
    return self.username



#forms.py
class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePic
        fields = ['text','thumbnail']

#models.py
class ProfilePic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='%(class)s_user', null=True)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=4096)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to='media', null=True)

#views.py
if request.POST:
username = request.session['username']
member_obj = Member.objects.get(pk=username)

    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
    profile_pic = form.save(commit=False) 

   **#checking if username already exists in the DB:**

    member_obj = Member.objects.update_or_create(username=username)

   **#if yes then replace data in the row with the new one,
     # if not create a new row**  

    profile_pic.user = member_obj
    profile_pic.save()
```

Comment: Where is `username` coming from here?

Comment: Do you want check  is membe exist or not and want to update profile_pic right ??

Comment: yes i want to check if `username` exists in the db already, if it does then replace the row with the new data provided in the form

Comment: in username which value you are passing user id or username ?
because ur checking for pk in your code

Comment: post your member model also

Comment: and exactly which field and which data you want to update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        username = request.session['username']
        if Member.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            member_obj = Member.objects.get(username=username)
            profile_pic = ProfilePic.objects.get(user=member_obj)
            profile_pic.user = member_obj
            # you can update other fields by using object.field_name (e.g. profile_pic.text = request.POST.get['text']
            profile_pic.save()
        else:
            ProfilePic.objects.create(user=username)
        return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse(form.errors)
else:
    form = UploadFileForm
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i am getting this error in line `ProfilePic.save` : `unbound method save() must be called with ProfilePic instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
`

Comment: okay so it doesn't go into the if statement `if Member.objects.filter(username=username).exists():` even though the username exists in the db... goes straight into `else:
            ProfilePic.objects.create(user=username)
        return HttpResponse('success')`

Comment: exactly what value you are passing in username ? and please also post your member model

Comment: well the username i am logged with atm is 'lol' so in `username = request.session['username']` the username = lol

Comment: can you post your member model ?

Comment: in member model ' username ' is what type of field ?

Comment: ok as per your member model in username field id is getting stored as string because you are pass primary_key=True and in request of view function you are passing name for username instead of id.

Comment: well just updated the question and added another model i am using which is Messages, i am using the same technique and it works fine for me, its only when i use ProfilePic it is giving me problems because i am using forms and with messages i didnt use forms, i added all the fields manually

Answer (score 0):

You should change the queryset:

```
member_obj = Member.objects.get(pk=username)
```

to

```
member_obj = Member.objects.get(username=username)
```

if `username = request.session['username']` is the `username` attribute of the `user` object. If you work with `username`s (instead of `id`s) you have to enforce distinct usernames.

If you want to work with `pk` (`id`) you should store it in session and then the query would be:

```
user_id = request.session['id']
member_obj = Member.objects.get(pk=user_id)
```

Comment: unfortunately this didnt work, it still creates a new row even though there is an entry for that username in the db

Comment: @user3395936 have you tried to work with the `id`s instead of `username`s?

Comment: well my whole project is based on validating usernames and not ids, i just don't want to change all my code and use id's.. and it doesn't fit with my app logic anyway

Answer (score 0):

As you did, `update_or_create` is here for that. However, you should use it as follow:

```
defaults = {} # Here you should specify the values that will be updated on the member object,
              # Or the default values to pass to the newly created instance

# Update or create return a tuple (object, created), created being a boolean
member_obj, created = Member.objects.update_or_create(username=username, defaults=defaults)

# This part seems correct to me
profile_pic.user = member_obj
profile_pic.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am a little confused as to what i need to be putting in defaults, because my data comes from forms.. so user, text, thumbnail is in forms, how would i put them in these curly braces? apologies if this is a stupid question, i am new to django and python in general

Comment: Your form data is present in `form.cleaned_data`, which is a dictionary (curly braces are a way to declare dictionaries in Python, dictionaries are key/value stores). So you can just do `defaults['field_name'] = cleaned_data['field_name']` to get the values you want to keep from cleaned data.